# NgRx Marbles Testing of an Effect returns weird error

Tags: angular, angular5, ngrx, ngrx-effects, jasmine-marbles

I have an Angular 5 app that uses NgRx Effects. One of the Effects handles Signup to a website by passing data entered by the user to a NodeJS Backend. The Effect works exactly as intended but when I try to unit test it with Marbles, I get a weird error.

This is the Effect:

```
@Effect()
  authSignup$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(AuthActions.TRY_SIGNUP)
    .switchMap((signUpData: {
      first_name: string,
      last_name: string,
      username: string,
      password: string,
      type: string,
      agreement: boolean
    }) =>
      this.httpClient.post(
      '/custom-endpoint',
      {
        first_name: signUpData.first_name,
        last_name: signUpData.last_name,
        username: signUpData.username,
        password: signUpData.password,
        type: signUpData.type,
        agreement: signUpData.agreement
      },
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        })
      })
      .map((res) => {
        return new AuthActions.SuccessfulSignup();
      })
      .catch((error: {reason: string}) => {
        return Observable.of(new AuthActions.UnsuccessfulSignup({reason: error.reason}))
      })
    );
```

This is the Unit Test with Marbles. It follows Todd Motto's guidelines for testing NgRx Effects.

```
export class TestActions extends Actions {
  constructor() {
    super(empty());
  }

  set stream(source: Observable<any>) {
    this.source = source;
  }
}

export function getTestActions() {
  return new TestActions();
}

fdescribe('AuthEffects', () => {

  let actions$: TestActions;
  let effects: fromEffects.AuthEffects;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        CookieModule.forRoot(),
        StoreModule.forRoot({...fromGlobal.reducers}),
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        fromEffects.AuthEffects,
        CookieAesService,
        { provide: Actions, useFactory: getTestActions },
      ],
    });
    actions$ = TestBed.get(Actions);
    effects = TestBed.get(fromEffects.AuthEffects);
  });

  it('should attempt to Sign Up the user', () => {
    const trySignup = new fromActions.TrySignup({
      first_name: 'test',
      last_name: 'test',
      password: 'test',
      username: 'test@test.com',
      type: 'test',
      agreement: false
    });
    const unsuccessfulSignup = new fromActions.UnsuccessfulSignup({ reason: 'test' });

    actions$.stream = hot('a', { a: trySignup });
    const expected = cold('b', { b: unsuccessfulSignup });
    expect(effects.authSignup$).toBeObservable(expected);
  });
});
```

Finally, this is the error I get in Karma:

```
Expected $.length = 0 to equal 1.
Expected $[0] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 0, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: UnsuccessfulSignup({ payload: Object({ reason: 'test' }), type: 'UNSUCCESSFUL_SIGNUP' }), error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }).
```

I deduce from this rather cryptic error message that the `trySignup` action was fired, but not the `unsuccessfulSignup` action. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alex, Am also facing the same error. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Bharat Hi, no I wasn't able to fix it. According to others who reported this bug in StackOverflow, there may be a bug with hot and/or cold Observables in the library, which causes this. I don't have more information at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex,

Your switchMap switches the stream over to the `http.post` stream, which you are not stubbing or returning. You need to emit an error from the `HttpClientTestingModule` first for the `catch` event to fire.

See the link below for an example:

https://medium.com/@Jestfer/testing-http-requests-in-angular-with-httpclienttestingmodule-3880ceac74cf